# How can I merge two dataframes, keeping overlapping values and NaN for other values, using only timestamps from the first dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've got two dataframes, one of which is a timestamp, and the other also has timestamps, but has gaps in it. The two dataframes have some overlap in timestamps, and some not. MWE:

This code creates the first dataframe:

```
daterange = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2023 09:30:00', end='1/3/2023 09:35:00', freq = 'min') 

daterange_keep = (pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.to_datetime(daterange))
          .indexer_between_time('09:30', '09:35') 
       )

firstdf= pd.DataFrame(daterange[daterange_keep])
firstdf.columns = ['timestamp']
firstdf
```

This creates the following dataframe, with times from 9:30 to 9:33, 1 Jan to 3 Jan:

[image]

The second dataframe looks like this:

```
seconddf = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': ['2023-01-01 09:30:00', '2023-01-01 09:32:00', '2023-01-01 09:34:00', '2023-02-01 09:30:00'], 'value': [3,5,7,9]})
seconddf
```

[image]

I want to merge the two dataframes, keeping all the timestamps in the first dataframe and inserting NaNs for the missing data from the second dataframe, and dropping all the data in the second frame that isn't in the first frame. The desired output is:

[image]

What is the best way to do this? (Ideally I'll also be able to rename the 'value' column but I assume I can do that independently of the merge.)

The obvious way appears to be `firstdf.merge(seconddf, how = 'inner')`, but this yields an error that says I should use `concat` instead, and I can't figure out how `concat` can achieve this merge.

Comment: at first make seconddf dtype to datetime , next `merge`. merge need same dtype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you missed to convert `timestamp` of your second dataframe to `datetime64`?

```
seconddf['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(seconddf['timestamp'])
out = firstdf.merge(seconddf, on='timestamp', how='left')
```

Output:

```
>>> out
             timestamp  value
0  2023-01-01 09:30:00    3.0
1  2023-01-01 09:31:00    NaN
2  2023-01-01 09:32:00    5.0
3  2023-01-01 09:33:00    NaN
4  2023-01-01 09:34:00    7.0
5  2023-01-01 09:35:00    NaN
6  2023-01-02 09:30:00    NaN
7  2023-01-02 09:31:00    NaN
8  2023-01-02 09:32:00    NaN
9  2023-01-02 09:33:00    NaN
10 2023-01-02 09:34:00    NaN
11 2023-01-02 09:35:00    NaN
12 2023-01-03 09:30:00    NaN
13 2023-01-03 09:31:00    NaN
14 2023-01-03 09:32:00    NaN
15 2023-01-03 09:33:00    NaN
16 2023-01-03 09:34:00    NaN
17 2023-01-03 09:35:00    NaN
```

You can also use:

```
dmap = seconddf.set_index('timestamp')['value']
firstdf['value'] = firstdf['timestamp'].map(dmap)
```

Using indexing:

```
out = (seconddf.set_index('timestamp')
               .reindex(firstdf['timestamp'])
               .reset_index())
```